# ListBox with hierarchy / tree-view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, tree

My domain consists of hierarchies and I want to display it to the user and allow selection of nodes.

What I seek is a way to blend a list-box with a tree-view, something like in Explorer's navigation side-bar.

[image: Windows Explorer's Navigation]

What would be an elegant way to do this?

*The root nodes (those that can be expanded) should be select-able as well just like directories are in Windows Explorer*

My domain (and view-model) looks something like this:

```
interface INode
{
    String Title { get; set; } // The header
    IEnumerable<Node> SubNodes { get; }

    // Some other irrelevant stuff

}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/264573/Replacing-TreeView-with-ListBox), may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an elegant way to do this. Populate your TreeView using your Object graph and a HierarchicalDataTemplate. I usually don't encourage the use of names within Xaml but this is one solution where it makes life simple.

Give the TreeView an x:Name (never use Name as not all controls support it) and bind the ItemsSource of the Listbox or ListView to

```
{Binding ElementName=TreeViewName, Path=SelectedItem.SubNotes}
```

So your Xaml will read something like.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._21657576.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:this="clr-namespace:StackOverflow._21657576"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubNodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.SubNodes}" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have changed the Node class to

```
public class Node
{
    public String Title { get; set; } // The header
    public ObservableCollection<Node> SubNodes { get; set; }
}
```

And the Nodes property on the ViewModel is

```
public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
```

This XAML will work if supplied with a valid collection of Node objects.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excuse me (I have not worked with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` before), but how does it connect to `TreeView`? I think I'm missing something in this since my project only shows the top-level node's header.

Comment: In the code above, the TreeView has no ItemTemplate specified so WPF searches for a data template to use for each node. This is handy as I can populate my treeview with multiple types and wpf will find their templates based on type. I could have assigned a key to the HierarchicalDataTemplate and the set ItemTemplate="{StaticReference templateName}". You need to use the HierarchicalDataTemplate because the ItemsSource of the template is used to populate the next level of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building this control yourself, simply using `ItemsControl` and DataTemplates.

For example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="vm:Node">
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubNodes}">
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <!-- Specify template for subnodes here -->
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            </Stackpanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I think you can build on that and customize it to your needs. In the example above nothing is selectable though. There are many approaches to achieve this behavior with `ItemsSource` and without.

One would be to use a list box, instead of the outer ItemsControl and set a custom control template in the `ItemContainerStyle`. I hope this gets you going, please keep asking if it doesn't. Good luck!